# Как запустить в консоли скрипт с заданной версией интерпретатора?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

У меня на компьютере стоят две версии Python: 3.7 и 3.8.

Как мне запустить скрипт именно с версией 3.7?

И можно ли как-то настроить команды для этого, например: py37 для 3.7 и py38 для 3.8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запускайте через `py` с указанием версии, например: `py -3.7 script.py`.

См. [Python Launcher for Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows), [PEP 397 -- Python launcher for Windows](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/)